# How set h2 tcp server to listen on tcp over IPv4?

Tags: java, tcp, h2

I create a small app with mixed mode of h2. Database is local and allow remote connections at the same time. Remote connection are by tcp. To start tcp server I use this code:

```
 public Server h2Server() throws SQLException {
        return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9092");
    }
```

Problem is that app server listen only on tcp6 (IPv6).

How can I change settings that app will listen on tcp (IPv4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it by starting `java`, i.e your app, with `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`